# Locking not working with OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I'm stuck with an issue in my OpenCL code where I try to synch inside a kernel:

```
__kernel void pdiffs (__global const long2 *inData, __global const long2 *inData2, __global long2 *outData) {
  long2 diffSum = 0;
  uint idx0 = get_local_size(0)*get_group_id(0);
  for (uint idx=idx0; idx<idx0+get_local_size(0); idx += 1) {
    diffSum += inData[idx] -  inData2[idx];
  outData[get_group_id(0)] = diffSum;
  printf("%d %d %d %d/%d\n", get_group_id(0), get_num_groups(0), get_local_size(0), diffSum.x, diffSum.y);
  barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE|CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
  if (get_group_id(0) == 0) {
    for (size_t i = 1; i < get_num_groups(0); i++){
      outData[0] += outData[i];
      printf("v(%d): %d/%d\n", i, outData[i].x, outData[i].y);
    }
  }
}
```

(I know that this piece of code is simply bad...)

I just thought that the barrier will synch the single groups so the values in `outData` are defined. But my trace shows that some differences are not calculated and contain zero (I setup my data so all shall return the value 1, but some display as 0). Further it makes a difference whether I have `printf` statements or not. Without `printf` even more differences seem to be incorrect.

Comment: `outData[get_group_id(0)] = diffSum;` Data race, all work items in a group write to same memory location. `outData[0] += outData[i];` Data race, all the work items in group0 write to same memory location.

Comment: Also barrier synch work items in a workgroup, it won't synch all work groups as you are trying. To achieve this you need to split your kernel into 2. By default the command queue is in-order which means second kernel will start after all work groups of first kernel have finished.

Comment: @doqtor If you have a solution for what I want, I' be happy.

Comment: @DarkZeros Also to you: if you have a solution, please post an answer. Thanks!